# monitor changes to a file in R (similar to tail "follow")

Tags: r

I'm wondering if there's a way to monitor the contents of a file from within R, similar to the behavior of `tail -f` (details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18760/how-does-the-tail-commands-f-parameter-work)) in the Linux terminal.

Specifically, I want a function that you could pass a file path and it would

- print the last `n` lines of the file to the console
- hold the console
- continue printing any new lines, as they are added

There are outstanding questions like "what if previously printed lines in the file get modified?" and honestly I'm not sure how `tail -f` handles that, but I'm interested in streaming a log file to the console, so it's kind of beside the point for my current usage.

I was looking around in the `?readLines` and `?file` docs and I feel like I'm getting close, but I can't quite figure it out. Plus, I can't imagine I'm the first one to want to do this, so maybe there's an established best practice (or even an existing function). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: R has no built-in way to do this, and the API for doing this is highly system dependent. Unless an R package already implements it, this might be a lot of work. However, take a look at the `fswatch` utility. It’s a command-line application that implements many different file system watch libraries across multiple operating systems. It might be easiest to create an `fswatch` process in your R code and communicate with it via a pipe (or, if you only need the `tail -f` functionality, you could just invoke that).

Answer (score 2):

I made progress on this using the `processx` package. I created an R script which I named `fswatch.R`:

```
library(processx)

monitor <- function(fpath = "test.csv", wait_monitor = 1000 * 60 * 2){
  system(paste0("touch ", fpath))
  
  print_last <- function(fpath){
    con <- file(fpath, "r", blocking = FALSE)
    lines <- readLines(con)
    print(lines[length(lines)])
    close(con)
  }
  
  if(file.exists(fpath)){
    print_last(fpath)
  }
  
  p <- process$new("fswatch", fpath, stdin = "|", stdout = "|", stderr = "|")
  
  while(
      # TRUE
      p$is_alive() & 
      file.exists(fpath)
    ){
    p$poll_io(wait_monitor)
    p$read_output()
    
    print_last(fpath)
    
    # call poll_io twice otherwise endless loop :shrug:
    p$poll_io(wait_monitor)
    p$read_output()
  }

  p$kill()
}

monitor()
```

Then I ran the script as a "job" in RStudio.

Every time I wrote to `test.csv` the job printed the last line. I stopped monitoring by deleting the log file:

```
log_path <- "test.csv"
write.table('1', log_path, sep = ",", col.names = FALSE, 
            append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
write.table("2", log_path, sep = ",", col.names = FALSE, 
            append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
unlink(log_path)
```